# Communicating with a BlueSMiRF device from ios

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I need to use an iPhone to send data to an arduino, which is hooked up to a [BlueSMiRF](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12577) device. Which iOS libraries should I use to send data over the bluetooth connection? I am new to using bluetooth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you use Apples own `CoreBluetooth`.  If you need any help setting it up feel free to use my sample project in order to setup your own.  You can find it [Here](https://github.com/FredLoh/BLE-Swift-Base)

In order to use it simply change the following to the properties of your device. If you do not know what the device name, serviceUUID or characteristicUUID are you can use an app like [LightBlue](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue-explorer-bluetooth/id557428110?mt=8) to find it.  Let me know if you need any help.

`//Change these settings
    let deviceName = "Bluno"
    let deviceUUID = NSUUID(UUIDString: "DBBD02C8-765D-4340-95DC-35A7C69F420A")
    let serviceUUID = "DFB0"
    let characteristicUUID = "DFB1"
    let message = "5"`

As a note for anybody looking to do this in the future.  This is not possible since BlueSMiRF is not BLE.  You'd have to get special approval from apple which they seem to do more for people trying to produce headphones etc.

Comment: It is, is the BlueSMiRF not BLE?  If it is not then you will not be able to do what you are looking to do with an iPhone.

Comment: Hmm.... it uses the old type of Bluetooth, the same as a pair of wireless headphones where you go into your iPhone settings to pair with.

Comment: I did some research and it says that is it possible, but it needs some MFI program libraries. I am new to xCode, please tell me what this is.

Comment: Good luck. https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action  You need to get special permission.  From the faq: Developers who wish to develop electronic accessories for iPhone, iPad or iPod using licensed technology should join the MFi Program. Companies, organizations, government entities and educational institutions are eligible to apply. For more information, please see the Who needs to join the MFi Program and Who does not need to join the MFi Program sections below.